# How can I upload multiple files to a firebase storage ref using javascript ?

Tags: javascript, firebase, upload, firebase-storage

The Put method for the firebase storage seems to only take one file at a time. How do I get this to work with multiple files ? I am trying to wait for each upload to finish and collect a download url for each, then proceed and save these urls in an array in a node in the realtime database, but I can't seem to figure the best way to handle this.

Comment: You can call `put()` for each file you want to upload. If you're having problems making this work, share the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/d4f1327b58ad69334ef06327184df790) of this:

```
// set it up
firebase.storage().ref().constructor.prototype.putFiles = function(files) { 
  var ref = this;
  return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
    return ref.child(file.name).put(file);
  }));
}

// use it!
firebase.storage().ref().putFiles(files).then(function(metadatas) {
  // Get an array of file metadata
}).catch(function(error) {
  // If any task fails, handle this
});
```